# Angular 5 canActivate always return to login page for specific route

Tags: angular, canactivate

I'm trying to secure my app from unauthorized users, by defining routes guard and assigning canActivate to each wanted-to-be-secure route. Everything is going fine on those routes, for example when someone want to access route from url it will redirect automatically to login page unless if he/she is logged in then the app will redirect to the specific route. But there is one route, when user is logged in it always return to the login page. This issue occurs on the route `'/verify/:idC'`, what should I do?

routing.ts:

```cpp
{ path: 'verify/:idC', component: VerifyRoleComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
```

auth-guard.ts:

```cpp
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

import { AuthService } from '../auth/auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) { }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) : boolean {
    let url: string = state.url;

    return this.checkLogin(url);
  }

  checkLogin(url: string): boolean {
    if (this.authService.isLoggedIn) { return true; }

    // Store the attempted URL for redirecting
    this.authService.redirectUrl = url;

    // Navigate to the login page with extras
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    return false;
  }

}
```

auth.service.ts:

```cpp
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  isLoggedIn = false;

  constructor() { }

  // store the URL so we can redirect after logging in
  redirectUrl: string;

  login(): Observable<boolean> {
    return Observable.of(true).delay(1000).do(val => this.isLoggedIn = true);
  }

  logout(): void {
    this.isLoggedIn = false;
  }

}
```

verify-component.ts:

```cpp
@Component({
  selector: 'app-verify-role',
  templateUrl: './verify-role.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./verify-role.component.scss']
})
export class VerifyRoleComponent implements OnInit {

  auth: Auth;

  constructor(private credService: CredentialService, private authService: AuthService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {    
    const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('idC');
    console.log(id) ;

    this.route.paramMap
      .switchMap((params: ParamMap) => 
        this.credService.getAccountId(params.get('idC')))
          .subscribe(res => {
            this.auth = res;
            console.log(this.auth);
            if (res.role.toString() == "User"){
              let idC = res.account;
              this.loginUser(idC);
            } else {}
          }, err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
  }

  loginUser(idC:string) {
    this.authService.login().subscribe(() => {
      if (this.authService.isLoggedIn) {
        let redirect = this.authService.redirectUrl ? this.authService.redirectUrl : '/profile/'+idC;
        this.router.navigate([redirect]);
      }
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: due to loginUser method conditions fails

Comment: I got it, so how can I solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you must add an else before `this.router.navigate(['/login']);`

Comment: I tried it right now. Nothing happens, it remains the same issue.

Comment: into the condition this.authService.isLoggedIn  you should navigate to the redirectUrl . so add  this.router.navigate([redirectUrl ]);

Comment: The same thing,  @user3529601